# Having trouble while launching localhost in WampServer 3

Tags: wamp, wampserver

After installing WampServer 3 on Windows 7, I deleted default file and copied my project folder into `www` folder of the WAMP.

Then I lanched `localhost` via my browser and got this error

> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

I have similar problem with `WampServer 2.5`.

Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please know that your question doesn't provide nearly enough detail for us to give you a good answer. I encourage you to look at some of the other questions on this site to get a sense of what this site is all about. Then come back and expand on your question, at least with a relevant sample of what you are doing and the error generated.

Comment: Never put anything in the `\wamp\www` folder. [Create a Virtual Host for each project, WAMPServer3 even provides a script to automate the process](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,138295) and [here are some reasons why Virtual Hosts are a good idea](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757)